# how to detect tab focus change in @react-navigation/bottom-tabs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am using **@react-navigation/bottom-tabs** in my react-native project..
there are three tabs

```
| Home | Add | List |
```

all these screens are supposed to fetch data using 3 different APIs and show it when user visit those tabs.. but the problem is how do i detect when a tab got focus?

i tried to use the **useIsFocused()**, but its not working...
suppose i have an API call **GetStudentsName()** in **Home-screen** , and i want it to run whenever the user visits the **HomeTab**....but when i click on the **Add tab**, then also this **GetStudentsName()** Api is getting called!...

how can i limit this api call only when the tab gets focus, **and not when the tab loses focus**?

please provide a hook-based solution instead of class based

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React Navigation provide an event handler to dispatch an event when user tap on the bottom tab icon or button.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("tabPress", async (e) => {
     // add your business logic here
    })

// Unsubscribe to event listener when component unmount
 return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [ navigation]);
```

Comment: wow...perfect solution... thanks @BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel

Comment: Can you please approve the answer as correct ?  This will help future developers to take reference

Answer (score 2):

in version 6.x of react-navigation you might want to check out `useIsFocused` hook.

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

// ...

function Profile() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return <Text>{isFocused ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>;
}
```

this causes a rerender so you might want to use `React.memo`

Answer (score 0):

```
 useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      return () => {
        //your code here
      };
    }, [])
 );
```